# Asymptote: maintain window size while changing POV in animation

Tags: 3d, asymptote, animations

In every Asymptote animation example that I found (see e.g. [here](http://www.piprime.fr/developpeur/asymptote/animation-asy_asy/?posts_per_page=-1) or [here](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/gallery/animations/index.html)), the viewpoint is constant during the animation. I would like to make one which consists in a rotating viewpoint, the drawn objects being constant.

The following code works, but as you can see the resulting `gif` is unsteady. How can I avoid this?

[image: problem illustration]

```
size(10cm,10cm);
import graph3;
import grid3;
//import animation;
import animate;

settings.render=1;
animation A;
A.global=false;

real xmin=-2, xmax=2;
real ymin=-2, ymax=1.5;
real zmin=-2.5, zmax=2.5;

limits((xmin,ymin,zmin),(xmax,ymax,zmax));

unitsize(3cm,3cm,2cm);

viewportmargin=(2,2);


////// PLANES ///////
pen bg=gray(0.9)+opacity(0.2);
draw(surface((xmax,ymin,zmin)--(xmax,ymin,zmax)--(xmin,ymin,zmax)--(xmin,ymin,zmin)--cycle),bg);
draw(surface((xmin,ymax,zmin)--(xmin,ymax,zmax)--(xmin,ymin,zmax)--(xmin,ymin,zmin)--cycle),bg);
draw(surface((xmax,ymax,zmin)--(xmax,ymin,zmin)--(xmin,ymin,zmin)--(xmin,ymax,zmin)--cycle),bg);


xaxis3(Label("$x$",MidPoint,align=Y-Z),Bounds(Both,Min),InTicks(Step=1),p=black);
yaxis3(Label("$y$",MidPoint,align=X-Z),Bounds(Both,Min),InTicks(Step=.5),p=black);
zaxis3(Label("$z$",MidPoint,align=X-Y),Bounds(Both,Min),InTicks(Step=2),p=black);

for(real i;i<6.28;i=i+0.05) {
  currentprojection=perspective(camera=(2*cos(i),2*sin(i),2.5));    
  A.add();
  save();
}

A.movie(loops=3,delay=50);
```

**Edit** I followed Harish Kumar's suggestion and added a bounding box; it's better but still far from perfect.

[image]

Code (only the end changes):

```
for(real i;i<6.28;i=i+.1) {
  currentprojection=perspective(camera=(2*cos(i),2*sin(i),2.5));
  picture pic;
  add(pic,bbox(20mm));  
  A.add(pic);
  save();
}
```

Comment: I don't know how but you can define a fixed bounding box.

Comment: @HarishKumar: I added your suggestion to my answer; the result is still unsteady.

Comment: What if you add it outside the loop and make it some what large enough?

Comment: @HarishKumar Well, if I add `bbox(5000mm);` or `shipout(bbox(5000mm));` outside the loop in my first code, it has no effect (that's why I added it in the loop).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is better to insert a sphere, its projection does not depend on the camera (in this case). Please find the code

```
size(10cm,10cm);
import graph3;
import grid3;
//import animation;
import animate;

settings.render=1;
animation A;
A.global=false;

real xmin=-2, xmax=2;
real ymin=-2, ymax=1.5;
real zmin=-2.5, zmax=2.5;

limits((xmin,ymin,zmin),(xmax,ymax,zmax));

unitsize(3cm,3cm,2cm);

viewportmargin=(2,2);


////// PLANES ///////
pen bg=gray(0.9)+opacity(0.2);
draw(surface((xmax,ymin,zmin)--(xmax,ymin,zmax)--(xmin,ymin,zmax)--(xmin,ymin,zmin)--cycle),bg);
draw(surface((xmin,ymax,zmin)--(xmin,ymax,zmax)--(xmin,ymin,zmax)--(xmin,ymin,zmin)--cycle),bg);
draw(surface((xmax,ymax,zmin)--(xmax,ymin,zmin)--(xmin,ymin,zmin)--(xmin,ymax,zmin)--cycle),bg);

xaxis3(Label("$x$",MidPoint,align=Y-Z),Bounds(Both,Min),InTicks(Step=1),p=black);
yaxis3(Label("$y$",MidPoint,align=X-Z),Bounds(Both,Min),InTicks(Step=.5),p=black);
zaxis3(Label("$z$",MidPoint,align=X-Y),Bounds(Both,Min),InTicks(Step=2),p=black);
draw(scale(4,4,5)*unitsphere,invisible);

for(real i;i<6.28;i=i+0.05) {
  currentprojection=perspective(camera=(2*cos(i),2*sin(i),2.5));
  A.add();
  save();
}

A.movie(loops=3,delay=50);
```

You obtain this animation

[image]

O.G.

Comment: or `draw(scale(4,4,5)*unitsphere,opacity(.0));` so one can change the opacity easily to check if the sphere *covers* everything.

Comment: Regarding transparency, the behaviour is due  to`settings.render=0;`. I forgot to change it to something `settings.render=1;` in my OP.

Comment: Code and gif animation modified.