# How does standalone crop?

Tags: standalone

I hope that this is not a duplicate. Consider the MWE

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\standaloneconfig{border=-3cm 0cm 0cm 0cm} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw(0,-5) grid (10,5);
\foreach \X in {0,...,10}
\node[circle,fill,label=45:{\X}] at (\X,0){};
\node at (5,2) {border=\{$\langle\mbox{length}~(\mbox{left})~\rangle$
$\langle\mbox{length}~(\mbox{right})~\rangle$
$\langle\mbox{length}~(\mbox{bottom})~\rangle$
$\langle\mbox{length}~(\mbox{top})~\rangle$
\}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The image gets cut at the left, which is consistent with the manual (top of page 9)

[image]

However, if I do

```
\standaloneconfig{border=0cm -3cm 0cm 0cm}
```

instead, I get

[image]

i.e. the image gets cut at the bottom (rather than right side).

Overall, I think that the standalone crops according to

```
border={left bottom right top}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for cropping the title of this question! ;-)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Never read the documentation. Bad things happen. --- David Carlisle

## Edit: [26/03/18]

Martin Scharrer just uploaded version 1.3 of `standalone.cls` to [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/standalone?lang=en), which has the correct order of the `border` option: `border={left bottom right top}`.

---

Older versions of the `standalone` manual have the order of the `border` option switched. The correct order of the borders is:

```
border={<length (left)> <length (bottom)> <length (right)> <length (top)>}
```

In line 57 of `standalone.cls` we see:

```
\default@bp\sa@border@left{#1}%
\default@bp\sa@border@bottom{#2}%
\default@bp\sa@border@right{#3}%
\default@bp\sa@border@top{#4}%
```

which is the correct order of the arguments.

Comment: Indeed `standalone` follows the usual left-bottom-right-top order. I apparently made an mistake when writing the manual.

Comment: I fixed this now in the code repository. Will be in the next version. https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/standalone/commits/ef6d3e2eeb053b8a0c654f90315c1329052b7276

Comment: @MartinScharrer In css the usual order is top-right-bottom-left, is the order left-bottom-right -top the standard in (la)tex world ?

Comment: @Kpym: I'm using the order also used by the `trim` key of the `graphicx` package, as my package is kind of a generalization of the `graphicx` key=value interface to general content. As `graphics`/`graphicx` is pretty old you could say this order is the standard.