# How to fill color between curves in Asymptote

Tags: asymptote

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{asymptote}

\begin{document}

\begin{asy}
size(5cm);
draw((0,0){up}--{right}(3,3){down}--{left}(1,1){right}--{up}(2,2){left}--{down}(0,0));
draw((0,0){up}..{right}(2,2){left}..{down}(1,1){right}..{up}(3,3){down}..{left}(0,0));
\end{asy}

\end{document}
```

It produces the following figure:

[image]

I want it to produce a figure like this:

[image]

P/s: I am a new Asymptote user ...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `filldraw` and the path must be a closed one, so you need to add `..cycle` and provide a color as `rgb(254,248,128)`. Note also that the `varwidth` option which suppresses the extra added width is used to have a symmetric standalone pdf.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{asymptote}

\begin{document}

\begin{asy}
size(0,150);
defaultpen(linewidth(1pt));
filldraw((0,0){up}..{right}(3,3){down}..{left}(1,1){right}..{up}(2,2){left}..{down}(0,0)..cycle,rgb(254,248,128));
filldraw((0,0){up}..{right}(2,2){left}..{down}(1,1){right}..{up}(3,3){down}..{left}(0,0)..cycle,rgb(128,127,255));
\end{asy}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

**Update**

To add a grid, use `add(grid(x,y));` after including `import geometry;`. You can change linetype, color, width, etc. of the grid. Here is an example:

```
\begin{asy}
import geometry;
size(0,150);
defaultpen(linewidth(1pt));
add(grid(3,3,gray+.5bp));
filldraw((0,0){up}..{right}(3,3){down}..{left}(1,1){right}..{up}(2,2){left}..{down}(0,0)..cycle,rgb(254,248,128)+opacity(.8));
filldraw((0,0){up}..{right}(2,2){left}..{down}(1,1){right}..{up}(3,3){down}..{left}(0,0)..cycle,rgb(128,127,255)+opacity(.8));
\end{asy}
```

> [image]

Comment: Can you use standalone environment for it ?

Comment: Sure, I edited my answer.

Comment: But, when I load it, there is extra white space on the left. How to fix it?

Comment: See edited my question ...

Comment: O.K., you need to provide the option `varwidth` to remedy this, see my edited answer.

Comment: See new question in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/466170/why-is-there-a-white-space-on-the-left-side and in the next time, we don't need using "varwidth" :-))

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for `varwidth` etc. if you use `asypictureB`, which comes with a couple of other advantages. Most notably, you can smuggle TeX macros in the asymptote code. (Compile e.g. with `pdflatex -shell-escape` The `filldraw` command is very nicely explained in the [tutorial by Charles Staats](https://math.uchicago.edu/~cstaats/Charles_Staats_III/Notes_and_papers_files/asymptote_tutorial.pdf), the author of `asypictureB`.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{asypictureB}

\begin{document}
\begin{asypicture}{name=fill}
size(0,150);
defaultpen(linewidth(1pt));
filldraw((0,0){up}..{right}(3,3){down}..{left}(1,1){right}..{up}(2,2){left}..{down}(0,0)..cycle,rgb(254,248,128));
filldraw((0,0){up}..{right}(2,2){left}..{down}(1,1){right}..{up}(3,3){down}..{left}(0,0)..cycle,rgb(128,127,255));
\end{asypicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity No.

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity When you compile it with `pdflatex -shell-escape`, `asy` will be automatically called, so you do not have to do it yourself. Smuggling in TeX macros refers to how, for example, I got the beak angle into the asy code in [this animation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/421887/121799).