# How to troubleshoot unwanted white spaces smartly?

Tags: asymptote

Why is there a white space on the left side?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{asy}
size(10cm,10cm);
draw((0,0)--(100,100));
draw((0,100)--(100,0));
dot((50,50));
\end{asy}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @chishimotoji: You must contact the package author to remove the white spaces.

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity I filed a bug report to one of the maintainers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Three unprotected end-of-lines in `asymptote.sty` (marked with `%<---`).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\makeatletter
\def\asy@init{%<---
  \def\ASYlatexdir{}%<---
  \ifx\asylatexdir\empty\else
    \def\ASYlatexdir{\asylatexdir/}%
  \fi
  \ifx\asydir\empty\else
    \def\ASYasydir{\asydir/}%
  \fi
  \def\ASYprefix{\ASYlatexdir\ASYasydir}%
}
\renewcommand\asy[1][]{%
  \stepcounter{asy}%
  \setkeys{ASYkeys}{#1}%
  \ifASYattach
    \ASYinlinefalse
  \fi
  \asy@init
  \immediate\write\AsyPreStream{%
    \noexpand\InputIfFileExists{%
      \ASYprefix\noexpand\jobname-\the\c@asy.pre}{}{}%
  }%<---
  \asy@write@graphic@header
  \let\ThisAsymptote\WriteAsyLine
  \ProcessAsymptote{asy}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{asy}
size(10cm,10cm);
draw((0,0)--(100,100));
draw((0,100)--(100,0));
dot((50,50));
\end{asy}

\end{document}
```

Note that `\noindent` is not necessary.

How to find them? I removed `\noindent` that does nothing with `standalone`, replacing it with

```
\tracingcommands=1 \tracingmacros=1
```

I compiled with `pdflatex`, ran `asy` and compiled again. The `.log` file is the searched for `{blank space}`:

```
\asy@init -> \def \ASYlatexdir {} \ifx \asylatexdir \empty \else \def \ASYlatex
dir {\asylatexdir /}\fi \ifx \asydir \empty \else \def \ASYasydir {\asydir /}\f
i \def \ASYprefix {\ASYlatexdir \ASYasydir }
{blank space  }
{\def}
{blank space  }
{\def}
{\immediate}

\ASYprefix ->\ASYlatexdir \ASYasydir 

\ASYlatexdir ->

\ASYasydir ->
{blank space  }

\asy@write@graphic@header ->\immediate \openout \AsyStream =\ASYasydir \jobname
```

It is apparent that `\asy@init` is responsible and indeed its definition is

```
\def\asy@init{
  \def\ASYlatexdir{}
  \ifx\asylatexdir\empty\else
    \def\ASYlatexdir{\asylatexdir/}%
  \fi
  \ifx\asydir\empty\else
    \def\ASYasydir{\asydir/}%
  \fi
  \def\ASYprefix{\ASYlatexdir\ASYasydir}%
}
```

showing two missing `%` protections.

Redefine the command and retry. Darn! There's still a blank space!

```
\ASYasydir ->
{blank space  }

\asy@write@graphic@header ->\immediate \openout \AsyStream =\ASYasydir \jobname
```

Look for `\asy@write@graphic@header` in `asymptote.sty`: we find it in the definition of `\asy`:

```
\newcommand\asy[1][]{%
  \stepcounter{asy}%
  \setkeys{ASYkeys}{#1}%
  \ifASYattach
    \ASYinlinefalse
  \fi
  \asy@init
  \immediate\write\AsyPreStream{%
    \noexpand\InputIfFileExists{%
      \ASYprefix\noexpand\jobname-\the\c@asy.pre}{}{}%
  }
  \asy@write@graphic@header
  \let\ThisAsymptote\WriteAsyLine
  \ProcessAsymptote{asy}%
}
```

Fix it and check again. Hurray! No spaces!

Comment: (+1) This nice fix should go into `asymptote.sty` soon! Thanks @egreg.

Comment: I believe this really shows how horrible LaTeX programming is... How can anybody conceive a language in which *comments* influence the execution?!

Comment: @Federico It's one of the reasons why `expl3` was born. On the other hand, TeX is a *typesetting* program, so spaces cannot generally be ignored.

Comment: @egreg  Good to know about `expl3`; I'll have a look. _"TeX is a typesetting program, so spaces cannot generally be ignored"_: that is just a severely bad separation of concerns in the TeX system, where there is no distinction between "typing mode" and "programming mode".

Comment: @egreg Many thanks I sent a mail to the authors, it is fixed.